# ReactJS - Submit form from parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to submit form from parent component  without using refs?

**Here is my code:**

```
const ModalWindow = ({ close }) => {
  const form = <MyForm />;

  return (
    <Modal show>
      <Modal.Body>
        {form}
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={close}>Cancel</Button>
        <Button onClick={form.submit}>Submit</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is the code you supplied working? Because you are not using refs in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `<Button type="submit">Submit</Button>` which will trigger your `<form onSubmit={}>` inside your component.